# SQL - Multiple Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

what i try to do is a multiple replace of an variable string.

but the problem that nothing happend.

i can´t figured out what is wrong in the code:

can someone give me hand with this pls?

here is the sql code:

```
SET @HTML = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@EMAILBODY2SEND,
                '@%LoginUser%@',@Name),
                '@%Number%@',@Number),
                '@%classification%@',@classification),
                '@%Phone%@',@Phone,
                '@%Date@',@Date)
```

Comment: You didn't close the bracket after @Phone, is that just a copy-paste issue or could be the cause of your problems?

Comment: Add an extra closing bracket and test. If still not working please provide an example of contents of `@EMAILBODY2SEND`?

Comment: lol :) it was the bracket that i have forget... lol.. thank you very much.. i have look to the code a lot of time and doesn´t see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope following query can make your life easier by not nesting too many parentheses.

```
SET @HTML = @EMAILBODY2SEND;
SELECT @HTML = REPLACE(@Html, P, R)
FROM (VALUES ('@%LoginUser%@',@Name),
            ('@%Number%@',@Number),
            ('@%classification%@',@classification),
            ('@%Phone%@',@Phone),
            ('@%Date@',@Date)
) AS T(P, R)
```

Comment: nice one, never saw like this ... just missing one comma after @Phone